Power Automate conditions
I have set up a workflow using SharePoint list and Power Automate, allowing users to choose up to five flights. The details of the first two flights are visible to all users. For additional flights, I've added a checkbox for users to select ("Add more flights"), allowing them to choose up to six flights.
My challenge is ensuring that the manager only receives details for the flights the user selects. If a user selects three flights, the manager should only see details for those three flights in the email. I've successfully implemented the first condition, but I need to figure out how to add the other conditions.


You only need to send one email. Work out what the email body needs to contain in a series of conditions. Write all the details into a variable. Once the variable is populated, you only send one email that takes the correct details for the email body from the variable.
At the top of the flow, initiate a variable for the email body.
Then use several different conditions that will append the flight details.
When a new item is created

initiate the string variable to blank text
append the first and second flight info to the variable
Condition: is the third flight selected
-- if yes, append flight info to the variable, if no, do nothing
Condition: is the fourth flight selected
-- if yes, append flight info to the variable, if no, do nothing
Condition: is the fifth flight selected
-- if yes, append flight info to the variable, if no, do nothing
Condition: is the sixth flight selected
-- if yes, append flight info to the variable, if no, do nothing
Condition: is the seventh flight selected
-- if yes, append flight info to the variable, if no, do nothing
send email with the variable in the email body


If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.
